# Recursively list directories in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

How do you recursively list directories in Powershell?

I tried `dir /S` but no luck:

```
PS C:\Users\snowcrash> dir /S
dir : Cannot find path 'C:\S' because it does not exist.
At line:1 char:1
+ dir /S
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\S:String) [Get-ChildItem], ItemNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PathNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand
```

Comment: get-childitem -recursive -directory, I believe it might not work with ps2

Comment: Short equivalents of `dir/s` are `gci -r`, `ls -r`, `dir -r`

Comment: @4c74356b41 It's `-recurse` not recursive. Recurse also has an alias of `-s` so `dir -s` would work.

Answer (score 72):

In PowerShell, `dir` is an alias for the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet.

Use it with the `-Recurse` parameter to list child items recursively:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse
```

If you only want directories, and not files, use the `-Directory` switch:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Directory
```

The `-Directory` switch is introduced for the file system provider in version 3.0.

For PowerShell 2.0, filter on the `PSIsContainer` property:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse |Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer}
```

*(PowerShell aliases support parameter resolution, so in all examples above, `Get-ChildItem` can be replaced with `dir`)*